# Error configuring: unknown option "-ipadx"

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface

I want to add `InPadding` to my `LabelFrame` i'm using AppJar GUI. I try this:
`self.app.setLabelFrameInPadding(self.name("_content"), [20, 20])`

But i get this error:

> appJar:WARNING [Line 12->3063/configureWidget]: Error configuring _content: unknown option "-ipadx"

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way containers are implemented in appJar, padding works slightly differently for labelFrames.

Try calling: `app.setLabelFramePadding('name', [20,20])`